# Moving images to new directories based on columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file, directory-structure

I am trying to move images to folders based on information present in a dataframe. The dataframe contains:

- ID column
- Image 1 filename path column
- Image 2 filename path column
- Image 3 filename path column

Every unique ID has three corresponding image file paths. I have been able to create a folder for each ID with the following code:

```
import os
root_path = ''
id_dirs = df['id'].unique().tolist()
for folder in id_dirs:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,str(folder)))
```

I would now like to move the images from their source directory to the newly created folders to achieve like shown below. Note that each filename is unique and all images are stored in the same directory.

```
folder/
├── ID_0/ 
│   ├── .../filename_0.png/
│   ├── .../filename_1.png/
│   ├── .../filename_2.png/
├── ID_1/ 
│   ├── .../filename_0.png/
│   ├── .../filename_1.png/
│   ├── .../filename_2.png/
├── ID_2/ 
│   ├── .../filename_0.png/
│   ├── .../filename_1.png/
│   ├── .../filename_2.png/
├── ID_3/ 
│   ├── .../filename_0.png/
│   ├── .../filename_1.png/
│   ├── .../filename_2.png/
|   |
etc.
```

```
# PSEUDO CODE
# if folder_name == df['id']:
#   move filename_0.png & filename_1.png & filename_2.png to that folder
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! check out the guide to [ask]. This seems like two questions in one - (a) how do I loop over the values of a dataframe? (which you've already answered) and (b) how do I move/rename files with python? There are a ton of answers to both of these on this site. Generally, bundling problems together into a full workflow isn't allowed - break down the problem into a single item and see if you can find an existing solution. That approach will probably help you sort out the problem on your own! Good luck :)

Comment: Can you show us how the dataframe of `Id` and the image name looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class example that does what you want.

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


class MoveFiles:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.df = kwargs.get("data")
        self.path = Path(f"{Path.home()}/Documents/")

    def main(self) -> None:
        mapping = self.df.set_index("id")["file_name"].to_dict()
        for folder, file in mapping.items():
            file = Path(self.path.joinpath(f"source/{file}"))
            self.move_files(folder, file)

    def move_files(self, folder: str, file: Path) -> None:
        Path(self.path.joinpath(f"destination/{folder}")).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        path = Path(self.path.joinpath(f"destination/"))
        try:
            file.rename(path / folder / file.name)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Couldn't find {file.stem} in source folder")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {
        "id": ["id_1", "id_2", "id_3"],
        "file_name": ["spam.rtf", "ham.rtf", "eggs.rtf"]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    MoveFiles(data=df).main()
```